# Proving $f$ is a power series centered at 0.

Tags: complex-analysis

By the definition of analytic function, if $f: \mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, then $f$ can be represented as a power series centered at 0? I think this straightly follows from the definition of the analytic function. I want to check if I am missing something or the statement is actually trivial.

$\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk.

Comment: If $ 0\in D $ then yes.

Comment: From the definition, this is only true locally, meaning that there is an open neighborhood of $0$ on which $f$ can be represented as a power series centered at $0$. It takes some more work to show that $\mathbb D$ itself is also such a neighborhood.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you for your comment. How can I show it holds for all $\mathbb{D}$, not only small open neighborhood of 0?

Comment: That's basically the content of Taylor's theorem, which requires Cauchy's generalized integral formula to prove. You can probably find it in your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. Indeed, for an analytic function $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, the radius of convergence when you develop $f$ in power series around a point $a \in U$ is at least $d(a, \mathbb{C}\setminus U)$.

Comment: It can also be larger. For instance, developing the main branch of the logarithm around $-1+\mathrm i$ results in a series with radius of convergence $\sqrt2$ (distance to the origin), not $1$ (distance to the negative real line).

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes you are right, thank you for the precision !